# Using backdrop blur in transparent flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to futter. I am making a flutter application which is transparent and has blur background on  its widgets. I have successfully created transparent application but I dont know how to add blur to the widgets.
I tried BackdropFilter but  it won't work.
Here is my blur code snippet:

```
    Center(
          child: ClipRect(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 9.0,
                sigmaY: 9.0,
              ),
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
                child: Text(_text),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Can anyone help me with bluring?

Comment: Have you tried Colors.transparent ?

Comment: Yes I have used Colors.transparent. And I am able to see my wallpaper. I want to add blur now. I am not sure how to do it.